Find one's game
Does this make sense if not how to say that?
I mean that one's game is not going well

Coutinho couldn't find his game at Barcelona


In his first season, Luka Modric, couldn't find his game


I think couldn't find his form would probably be more common, but in context, game is easily understood. They both mean he didn't achieve the high standard of play that might be expected. Not necessarily that he played badly - just not as well as he's capable of.

@Fumblefingers - absolutely standard sports-journalism expression. Mainly soccer.

@MichaelHarvey: Ilya Sorokin determined to find his game after rocky season. That's an ice hockey report in the New York Times. On this side of the pond, Can Wayne Rooney find his form for Manchester United? (years ago now, but on the first page of google results for "find his form").

@FumbleFingers - I've found plenty of UK and Ireland uses of 'game'.

@MichaelHarvey: All I said was I thought form would probably be more common than game. Maybe because it's more common in BrE, and for sure because it's more common among British snooker commentators (and it is the world championship right now, so that's my immediate environment! :) But I never suggested that game doesn't occur. And [find his] rhythm isn't uncommon in snooker commentary, but of course settle himself is far more common than everything else in that context.

@FumbleFingers - yes. I still find it odd that US media now routinely devote lots of space or time to what they call 'soccer'.

The notion of "finding one's game" (in football commentary) is achieving a state of playing skillfully in the style that suits the individual player.
So being unable to find one's game means not being settled. It might be because the player is forced to play a role for which they are not suited (eg if a striker has to defend deeply) or if the opposing team prevents the player from playing freely (the close marking stopped the midfield player from finding their game) Or just because the player is injured or not playing well for other reasons.

I don't think injury is a credible reason for a player being unable to find his game / form.

Why not?  If a player has (for example) a minor calf strain, it won't stop them from playing, but it may mean that they are unable to accelerate as much as they would like, which could put them off their game

I've never encountered the usage where "finding one's game" meant "overcoming physical limitations", regardless of whether those limitations arise from (temporary) injury or because of "congenital defects" (such as being born normal height, if you're a basketball player! :)
